# How to Save 2 forms in one view with Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I want to create a ticket (model Ventas) with his products (model Venta_detalle)

My models are:

```
class Ventas(models.Model): 
    metodo_pago = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)
    cajero = models.ForeignKey('auth.user')
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Clientes,blank=True,null=True)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)


class Venta_detalle(models.Model):
    venta = models.ForeignKey(Ventas)
    producto = models.ForeignKey(Productos)
    cantidad = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.producto.descripcion


class Productos(models.Model):
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    descripcion = models.TextField()
    precio_compra = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
    precio_venta = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
    existencia = models.IntegerField()
    impuesto = models.ForeignKey(Impuestos,blank=True,null=True)
    imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to='productos')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.descripcion
```

I need to create a lot of Venta_detalle objects with a product,quantity and Ventas ID in the same template.

For example: When we add a *ObjectInline(admin.TabularInline)* in admin panel to show two models with foreign key.

My view only have:

```
def VentasCrear(request):

    if request.method == "POST":        
        form = VentaForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            venta = form.save(commit=False)
            venta.cajero = request.user
            venta.save()
    else:
        form = VentaForm()

    return render(request, 'ventas.html',  {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 2):

> **En español:** Veo que lo que quieres es guardar una sola Venta y en ella
>   Guardar muchos detalles de esa venta, como los son los poductos y eso.
>   Como lo tienes esta bien pero le falta una parte, en la vista seria de
>   esta forma

I am also learning Python & Django, but I think what you want is to save a single Sale and in it save many many details of that sale, such as Productos. You're on the right track, but here is how to modify the view.

**def VentasCrear(request):**

```
if request.method == "POST": 
    # cuando llega el formulario los recibimos con sus respectivos prefijos (prefix) asi:
    #primero el formulario de Ventas       
    form = ventaform(request.POST, prefix="venta_form")
    #ahora recibimos el formulario de los detalles
    form2 = venta_detalle_form(reques.POST, prefix="venta_detalle_form")
    if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():  # si los formularios son validos
        venta = form.save(commit=False)
        venta.cajero = request.user
        venta.save() 
        # en este punto ya tienes la ventaguardada ahora procedes con los detalles    
        detalle = form2.save(commit=False)
        detalle.venta = venta # esta es la llave foranea de lo que guardamos arriba
        detalle.save()
else:   # este se cumpliria si es un GET
    formventa = ventaform(prefix="venta_form")
    formdetalle = venta_detalle_form(prefix="venta_detalle_form")
    context = { 'form' : formventa, 'form2' : formdetalle }

return render(request, 'ventas.html',  context)
```

Answer (score 1):

"*How to Save 2 forms in one view with Django?*"

In your `GET`, you initialize your forms with prefixes:

```
venta_form = VentaForm(prefix='venta_form')    
venta_detalle_form = VentaDetalleForm(prefix='venta_detalle_form')
context = { 'venta_form' : venta_form, 'venta_detalle_form' : venta_detalle_form }
return render(request, 'ventas.html',  context)
```

Then in your `POST`:

```
venta_form = VentaForm(request.POST, prefix='venta_form')
venta_detalle_form = VentaDetalleForm(request.POST, prefix='venta_detalle_form')
```

and there you go.